# toSql method in Laravel Eloquent is case sensitive?

Tags: php, laravel

I found out `toSql` method in Laravel is case-sensitive but as PHP docs it should not be like this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

> Note: Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.

When I use the method like this there is no problem

```
MyModel::where("sth","1")->toSql();
```

but when I use the method like this, I get the error: "method not found"

```
MyModel::where("sth","1")->tosql();
```

Can you please explain why this happen ?

Comment: As `toSql()` method defined into the `vendor/illuminate/database/Schema/Blueprint.php` file you need to use as it is defined not using `tosql()`.

Comment: @HirenGohel as php docs the methods are case-insensitive !!

Comment: Yes, but there are some functions you need to use using case sensitives. Like: `whereBetween`, `orWhereBetween`, `whereNotNull`, `toSql()` etc..